# Rearranging frame patterns with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Suppose a constant frame rate video has some occurrences of this frame pattern (same number means identical (considered by mpdecimate, for example) frames):

1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5

How to transform all these occurrences to:

1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5?

If it matters, video has duplicate frames only at the start of pattern occurrences and nowhere else.

Comment: Do you know the frame range where this pattern occurs?

Comment: @Gyan, there are multiple occurrences of the pattern. But since all of them start with 5 duplicate frames and moreover no other duplicate frames but at the start of these occurrences are present in the video, mpdecimate could locate every occurrence.

Comment: You can use the shuffleframes filter once you know the frame numbers where this pattern occurs.

Comment: @Gyan I made a .txt file with complete frame mapping, but it's too large (42103 frames, so 241508 chars) to pass it into cmd as "shuffleframes=..." string.